# ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError Migrations are pending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, database-migration

I think that problem in this migration, but I'm new on rails and do not sure.

```
 class AddPasswordDigestToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    remove_column "admin_users", "hashed_password"
    add_column "admin_users", "password_digest", :string
  end

  def down
    remove_column "admin_users", "password_digest"
    add_column "admin_users", "hashed_password", :string, :limit => 40
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks like you just need to run `rails db:migrate`

Comment: Mysql2::Error: Table 'blog_development.admin_users' doesn't exist: ALTER TABLE `admin_users` DROP `hashed_password`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the migration hasn't been executed properly. You could try resetting the database by doing `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` **This will drop the database and create a new one**

Comment: It doesn't help. ActiveRecord::NoEnvironmentInSchemaError: 

Environment data not found in the schema.

Comment: try running `rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV={{whatever}}` before each command

Comment: they say "rails aborted"

Comment: could you paste the full backtrace?

Comment: rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:enviroment:set' (see --tasks)
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:14:in `block in run_rake_task'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:11:in `run_rake_task'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/home/artem/ROR/blog/bin/rails:9:in `require'

Comment: nothing changes, Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

Comment: # Raises <tt>ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError</tt> error if any migrations are pending.
      def check_pending!(connection = Base.connection)
        raise ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError if ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration?(connection)
      end

      def load_schema_if_pending!